# Sort is not a function in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new in Mongodb. I am getting the following error --

`E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.events.findOne(...).sort is not a function :`

```
db.events.findOne({ 
    "userId" : {
        "$ne" : ""
    }, 
    "$and" : [
        {
            "userId" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}).sort({ 
    "_id" : -1
});
```

When I add limit then it works but without limit it doesn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#modify-the-cursor-behavior) which returns cursor and you can apply limit, skip, sort and collation. `db.events.find({ 
    "userId" : {
        "$ne" : ""
    }, 
    "$and" : [
        {
            "userId" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}).sort({ 
    "_id" : -1
});`

Comment: `findOne()` returns a single document. You cannot sort a single item. If you use `find()` then you will receive an array of documents, which you can sort.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen ahh so stupid I am. find() with limit(1) worked great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

`sort()` cannot be used with `findOne()` that way. I'd suggest using the following:

```
db.events.find({ 
    "userId" : {
        "$ne" : ""
    }, 
    "$and" : [
        {
            "userId" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}).sort({ 
    "_id" : -1
}).limit(1)
```